# How to check if whenever gem is working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I've got the following configuration. I've installed whenever gem, created shedule.rb:

```
# Learn more: http://github.com/javan/whenever

every 6.hours do
    runner "Part.check_status_update"
end
```

In part.rb model I have corresponding method.

**A.** How can I check if `whenever` runs? As I understand it should only modify the crontab after `whenever` command in the bash, yes?

**B.** If the method is not triggered - then how can I debug the scheduled jobs? If I put into my method `puts` statements - where shall they be stored or outputted?

Comment: 'Whenever' command just outputs lines in 'crontab' syntax. To actually update schedule you should run 'whenever --update-crontab'. But notice it will erase existing crontab!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define a log file, which will then receive any output from your `Part.check_status_update` call (such as `puts` calls). You can set a default log file for all of your jobs at the top of your `schedule.rb` file, such as:

```
set :output, '/path/to/file.log'
```

For example, to log to `Rails.root/log/whenever.log`:

```
set :output, 'log/whenever.log'
```

You can also define the output per-task:

```
runner "Part.check_status_update", :output => 'log/check_status_update.log'
```

See [the Whenever wiki entry on the subject](https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs) for a full explanation of details and options, such as logging errors to a separate file.